# how to remove trailing %20target= from url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Recently i have been using stackoverflow to fix many of my server errors.  Recently i have encountered the following error "NOT FOUND 404 error" for the following error.

I have seen from web master central that there are several hundred urls have trailing string "%20target=" I want to remove so that the url yield results.

here is the sample.  i wanted to change the following url from

www.example.com/one/two/three/four/five/For-Sale-26264.html%20target=

to

www.example.com/one/two/three/four/five/For-Sale-26264.html

How can i achieve this using htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%20` is actually a URL encoded space, so you can use a lazy select `(.+?)` to match as few characters as possible before the space  with `\s` and then `target`. The grouped match is available as a back reference with `$1` for the rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.+?)\starget= $1 [L]
```